# Detect chinese (multibyte) character in a string in a column in oracle database

Tags: oracle, character, detect, cjk

how can i detect that a column in oracle database has chinese (multibyte) characters in it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try "where length(column) < lengthb(column)"